# Rails app crashes when I hit the back button after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I implemented Devise in my Rails app as well as redirects after sign in:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resourse)
  case resource 
    when User
      # If the user profile isn't filled out, direct users there
      if current_user.user_profile.nil?
        return new_user_profile_path

      # If the profile isn't filled out, direct users there.
      elsif !current_user.user_profile.nil? && current_user.user_profile.profileable.nil?
        return new_dentist_detail_path
      elsif !current_user.user_profile.nil? && !current_user.user_profile.profileable.nil? && current_user.user_profile.competencies.count == 0
        return edit_competencies_path
      else
        return user_dashboards_show_path # ToDo: redirect to dashboard new
      end
```

Login and redirects work fine, but if I hit the back button after login, I get this:

```
Cannot redirect to nil!
#   redirect_to post_url(@post) and return
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
   raise ActionControllerError.new("Cannot redirect to nil!") unless options
   raise AbstractController::DoubleRenderError if response_body

   self.status        = _extract_redirect_to_status(options, response_status)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more of the error? This is just a guess because I can't see the entire error message, but most likely `@post` is nil, so you need check if `@post` is nil, if it is redirect to where you would like users to go in that situation.

Comment: I added a screen capture of the error and you're correct, @post is nil. I'm not sure where to check post though. The error seems to be happening in code internal to Devise.

Comment: Of course it does, you raise an error because `options` is empty after hitting back. You should have a *fallback location* to redirect to if no redirect options are provided